# Express GET Route not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, url-routing

I have developed a REST API using Node and Express. I am trying to fetch to do list items. Each `todo` list item consists of an id and text property. What I want to do is have a `GET` route which will allow me to get a specific `todo` list item by passing the id as the route parameter. I have tried several attempts but can't see what I am doing wrong. My code is :

**My Database**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
  text : String,
  done : Boolean
});

// get all todos list items
app.get('/api/todoo', function(req, res) {

  // use mongoose to get all todos in the database
  Todo.find(function(err, todos) {

  // if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.send(err) will execute
    if (err)
      res.send(err)

    res.json(todos); // return all todos in JSON format
  });
});


//Getting a todo list by ID

app.get('/api/todoo/:todo_id', function(req, res) {
  Todo.find({id : req.params.todo_id}, 
    function(err, todo) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      res.json(todos);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: did you put this in code, if not then you should

    Module.exports = app;

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo of having 'todoo' where you intend 'todo'?